# Domain is not resolved properly

Tags: amazon-route53, heroku

My site is hackertoolbox.com.

1. In Route53, there is a cname record whose value is hackertoolbox.herokuapp.com.
2. My domain uses the right route53 DNS. whois result matches the route53 delegation set.
3. hackertoolbox.herokuapp.com works well.
4. Neither hackertoolbox.com nor www.hackertoolbox.com works.

I've done similar setup a couple of times, but not sure why it doesn't work this time. I must do something wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
host www.hackertoolbox.com
www.hackertoolbox.com has address 174.37.172.71

nslookup 174.37.172.71
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
71.172.37.174.in-addr.arpa  name = 174.37.172.71-static.reverse.softlayer.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

dig www.hackertoolbox.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.hackertoolbox.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45559
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.hackertoolbox.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.hackertoolbox.com.  259 IN  A   174.37.172.71

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 26 16:57:24 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: Are you positive that it doesn't work? I would say that it appears to work...

Comment: Oh, thanks. Do both http://hackertoolbox.com and http://www.hackertoolbox.com work? I just tried to access the site from other places and seems it works (http://nibbler.silktide.com/en_US/reports/www.hackertoolbox.com), but not my computer/phone.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about what's wrong, DNS cache? 'host www.hackertoolbox.com' gives 'www.hackertoolbox.com has address 174.37.172.71'. The ip address is not expected.

Comment: It can take a full 24-72hrs for full propigation

Comment: Ok. Thanks all for the help. Then I will just wait.

Comment: The TTL is 60 seconds, so your local DNS resolver is broken.

Comment: Weird, accessing from browser is ok now though 'host domain' still gives the wrong IP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, how to fix the broken DNS?

Comment: Go find whoever is responsible for it?

Comment: This tool should be very useful for checking the DNS propagation. http://wheresitup.com/